# How do I detect if the browser window is active

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

The code im currently using is this

```
var focus;
function focuswindow() { focus = true; }
function hidewindow() { focus = false; }
window.onfocus = focuswindow();
window.onblur = hidewindow();
```

The idea is that it can be used like this

```
if( focus ) { //do something
}
```

However its not working. Also it only needs to work on Chrome (so no legacy IE stuff) since its for a Chrome extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is that you're calling the functions immediately and assigning the return value of `undefined` to `onfocus` and `onblur`.

Instead, `onfocus` and `onblur` should reference the functions by name.

Try this:

```
window.onfocus = focuswindow;
window.onblur = hidewindow;
```

Notice that I removed the `()` call operators. Now `onfocus` and `onblur` are referencing the functions, and will call them when the events occur.